# Gold (in) Bar vs Gold Bar vs Gold Bars

Tags: grammatical-number

I had a discussion with co-workers regarding correct usage of phrases relating to gold production. Namely, I suggested the following phrase: '**gold in bar production**' that is, production of gold in the form of bars or ingots or bullions. In our field of operations, gold refining and recovery, we use 'bar (s)' only. The other two words,bullions and ingots are not used in the industry. However, googling doesn't show a single example of this phrase but gives many examples of '**gold bar**' and '**gold bars**' - plural 'bars' is used mostly in the context of gold sales, while in the gold recovery business singular 'bar' prevails. I prefer the phrase '**gold in bar** (production)' based on the analogy with '**copper in concentrate**', and I am sure that grammatically this phrase is absolutely normal and correct. I will appreciate any professional opinions in this regard.